# How to Version Control Content (Posts, Pages) in WordPress When Working on Different Databases in Local and Production Environments with Git?

Tags: wordpress, git

I'm looking to implement version control for a WordPress website using Git, but I'm facing a challenge when it comes to version controlling content like posts and pages. I'll be working with different databases for local development and the production server. Since WordPress doesn't have migration files for content, what are the best practices and methods for effectively version controlling posts, pages, and other content in this scenario?

I'm interested in strategies and tools that will allow me to:

Maintain version history of content changes.
Sync content between my local and production databases.
Easily manage and track content modifications across different environments.
Ensure that content updates are coordinated and well-documented.
Any guidance and recommendations on how to approach this situation would be highly appreciated.